# unable to unpack list of dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have as list of object as below :

```
this_json_reponse = ['{"queskey": 1, "ques": "test question 1", "ans": "test ans 1"}', '{"queskey": 2, "ques": "test question 2", "ans": "test ans 2"}', '{"queskey":
5, "ques": "bfxgrdytreyt4etgest4", "ans": "3353tet4"}', '{"queskey": 6, "ques": "tet4w64t", "ans": "f464etrtd"}', '{"queskey": 7, "ques": "fdszf3r3647", "ans": "gry5757"}']
```

I receive this from another API call.
I need to simply list all the `queskey` and `ques` present :

1 : test question 1
2 : test question 2
...

I tried unpacking this with nested loop as below :

```
<ul>
    {% for this_item in this_json_reponse %}
    <li>{{ this_item }}</li>
        {% for a,b in this_item.items %}
            <li>{{ a }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

sadly I'm unable to do so after long hit/trial.

this is in my views.py def

```
    this_json_reponse=this_reponse.json()
    this_list=[]
    for item in this_json_reponse:
        this_list.append(item)
    return render (request,"listall.html",{"this_json_reponse": this_list})
```

Comment: The content of `this_json_reponse` is actually just a string, that happens to _look_ like dictionaries.  `this_json_reponse = ['...one big string...']`

Comment: I added this in views.py this_json_reponse=this_reponse.json()
    this_list=[]
    for item in this_json_reponse:
        this_list.append(item)
    return render (request,"listall.html",{"this_json_reponse": this_list})

Comment: If your code is incorrect in the question can you please edit it and put the correct version there? For your given template, what is actually rendering.

Comment: Can’t you just iterate over `json_response` and use `eval()` or parse it as JSON?

Comment: thanks a lot @JohnGordon